# Insert PHP variabel in SQL queries Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter to use some queries and this is my code so far. is my code correct?

```
$this->db->select("(SELECT SUM(grand_total) FROM Sales_order WHERE member = '2') - (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM payment WHERE member_id = '2')  AS total_sales");
```

and how to change number 2 with this variable
  `$this->session->userdata('ID')`

Comment: from doc https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html#query-bindings

Comment: thanks @HoàngĐăng I'll check this out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$this->db->select("(SELECT SUM(grand_total) FROM Sales_order WHERE member = '".$this->session->userdata('ID')."') - (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM payment WHERE member_id = '".$this->session->userdata('ID')."')  AS total_sales"');
```

Comment: sql injection ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Query Bindings](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#query-bindings) like below to escape it automatically:

```
$sql = "(SELECT SUM(grand_total) FROM Sales_order WHERE member = '?') - (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM payment WHERE member_id = '?')  AS total_sales";
$this->db->query($sql, array($this->session->userdata('ID'),$this->session->userdata('ID')));
```